# ExtJS and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-maps-api-3, extjs4

I'm trying to figure out how well ExtJS and Google Maps play together.  I'm playing with this example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/window/gmap.html

I get lost when I try to address the map.  I want to be able to programatically make changes to the zoom level, draw polygons and put points on the map.

I've been playing, so my code isn't the same as that in the example.

I've defined a form panel and I've embedded the map into it.  I have a listener that waits for the map to be rendered:

```
listeners:{
            afterrender: {
                fn: setupWindow,
                scope: this
            }
        }
```

Then, inside setupWindow I have this:

```
gmap.setzoom(25);
mapBounds = new gmap.LatLngBounds(
                new gmap.LatLng(responseJson.minY, responseJson.minX),
                new gmap.LatLng(responseJson.maxY, responseJson.maxX)
                );
```

But it fails in there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (just adding a comment, since it's not really an answer to your question). Have you tried OpenLayers, which provides access to gmap v3  + nice vector layers ?

Comment: I had, but the examples were v2 only?

Comment: how to handle click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling `gmap.setZoom(25)` in the line before the problematic one - I assumed that `gmap` is an instance of `GMap2` like so:

`var gmap = new GMap2(...);`

If that is indeed the case - then `new gmap.LatLngBounds` or `new gmap.LatLng` should fail, because neither is a function of `map` (unless you add it in your code).

What you perhaps should do instead is:

```
mapBounds = new GLatLngBounds(
                    new GLatLng(responseJson.minY, responseJson.minX),
                    new GLatLng(responseJson.maxY, responseJson.maxX)
                );
```

**EDIT**: to clarify my assumption - from the ExtJS example that you are trying to use it seems that you are trying to go with API V2.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand GMaps either, but what's in the ... in here new GMap2(...);?  I had tried this: var gmap = ext.get("gmappanel")

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking me what the ellipsis means in `GMap2(...)`? In that case - I simple don't know how you instantiated your gmap instance.

`Ext.get('gmappanel')` simply means that you've created it somewhere else. Possibly in `initComponent` of some panel in your ExtJS application.

Comment: I was being an idiot.  I figured out what you meant.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well... you are attempting to use Google Maps v3, while the ExtJS example is built with GMap v2.

Additionally, like ZenMaster points out, you have some kind of mess in your attempt to use the GMap API. From where does the gmap variable come from? Either use `new google.maps.LatLng` in v3, or `new GLatLng` in v2.

Comment: Ah... I see. LatLng is V3 only... V3 indeed.